# struct in struct task on C

Tags: c, function, pointers, text, struct

I am working on the program that gets information form file "stockroom.txt" and from "products.txt" then it stores data from files in the structures of the following type:

```
// data from "stockroom.txt"
struct ingredient {
    char* name;
    int number;
};
struct dose {
    int index;
    int amount;
};
// here data from products.txt
struct recipe {
    char* name;
    int price;
    int number_ing;
    int current_price;
    int best_price;
    struct dose* ingredients;
};
```

So, the problem occurs when I want to read the file "products.txt" and store its data to the struct. In particular, I have the following function:

```
void read_recipes(int nr, int ni, struct recipe* recipes[], struct ingredient* ingredients[], FILE* products){
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++){
        char tmp_s[31];
        int tmp_n, n;
    
        fscanf(products, "%s %d %d", tmp_s, &tmp_n, &n);
        recipes[i] = (struct recipe *)malloc(sizeof(struct recipe));
        recipes[i] -> name = strdup(tmp_s);
        recipes[i] -> price = tmp_n;
        recipes[i] -> number_ing = n;
        recipes[i] -> current_price = 0;
        recipes[i] -> best_price = 0;
        recipes[i] -> ingredients = NULL;

        for(j = 0; j < n; j ++){
            char tmp_name[21];
            int tmp_amount;
            struct dose* doses[n];
            doses[j] = (struct dose*)malloc(sizeof(struct dose));
            fscanf(products, "%s %d", tmp_name, &tmp_amount);
            for(k = 0; k < ni; k++){
                if(strcmp(ingredients[k] -> name, tmp_name) == 0){
                    doses[j] -> index = k;
                    doses[j] -> amount = tmp_amount;
                }
            }
            recipes[i] -> ingredients = doses; // error here?
        }
    }
}
```

Probably error is in the last row but I am not sure. Let me clarify what I want.

File "stockroom.txt" has this content:

```
6
flour 35
sugar 40
eggs 20
milk 25
cocoa 48
jam 10
```

Second file:

```
3
Easter_eggs 6 2
cocoa 8
milk 3
Sacher_cake 22 3
flour 4
cocoa 14
jam 2
Mimosa_cake 13 5
eggs 3
flour 4
sugar 6
milk 4
jam 2
```

struct dose* ingredients contains index of the product from the stockroom and amount of the product. However, by debugging I learned that it does not save all of the information but only last row. Help me please.

Last row of the code, where I am expecting the error, gcc writes this

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct dose' from type 'struct dose **'

How to fix it, I don't know.

Comment: Why don't you use a serialization library that knows how to do it? Aka Googles protobuf or similar? Also, you are allocating to `doses[j]` but then assigning all `doses` to your recipes.

Comment: The variable `doses` is local inside the loop. Each time the loop iterates, the scope and the variable life-time ends, and the pointer you save will become invalid. You need to allocate the array dynamically with `malloc`, each and every iteration of the loop. The whole `doses` part needs to be reworked actually, it's all wrong.

Comment: OT: To me your naming is very confusing. You have a `struct ingredient` and you have an array of pointers to that struct with the name `ingredients`. But inside `struct recipe` you also have a member with the name `ingredients` but it has the type pointer to `struct dose`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
I actually tried to make it in main function, it didn't work. But I will try to rework doses, thanks for help.

Comment: @SupportUkraine
Yeah, I know it, just didn't realize to change it when I was writing the code.

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess
 I am not allowed to use anything except what I am using now

Comment: hey @Someprogrammerdude
  I tried to move _struct dose* doses[n];_ to upper loop, still no changes actually. On the last line there is this error: _assignment to 'struct dose *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct dose **'_

Answer (score 1):

These changes solved the problem:

```
// ...
    recipes[i] -> ingredients = (struct dose*)malloc(sizeof(struct dose) * n);

    for(j = 0; j < n; j ++){
        char tmp_name[21];
        int tmp_amount;    
        struct dose* ingredient = (struct dose*)malloc(sizeof(struct dose));
        fscanf(products, "%s %d", tmp_name, &tmp_amount);
        for(k = 0; k < ni; k++){
            if(strcmp(ingredients[k] -> name, tmp_name) == 0){
                ingredient -> index = k;
                ingredient -> amount = tmp_amount;
            }
        }
        recipes[i] -> ingredients[j] = *ingredient;
    }
```

Comment: Please note that you also need to  `free()` the local variable `ingredient` or you are creating a memory leak. `recipes[i] -> ingredients[j] = *ingredient;` makes a hard copy of the contents of the struct, but the pointer `ingredient` still points at an allocated copy once the loop is done. You could probably just have allocated it as a local variable in this case and skipped malloc.